# Создание формы регистрации и профиля зарегестрированого пользователя

Tags: php

Добрый день. Подскажите, как создать форму регистрации и профиль зарегестрированого пользователя на сайте?

Answer (score 1):

1. Создать таблицу с полями пользователя в БД (логин, пароль и тд)
2. Написать форму регистрации на html
3. Написать скрипт регистрации, который будет заносить поля из формы в таблицу
4. Написать скрипт, который будет выводить поля

Как альтернатива - поставить CMS с присутствующим модулем пользователей. Или учить php.